# Union of inverted lists

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, information-retrieval, inverted-index

Give k sorted inverted lists, I want an efficient algorithm to get the union of these k lists?
Each inverted list is a read-only array in memory, each list contains integer in sorted order.
the result will be saved in a predefined array which is large enough. Is there any algorithm better than k-way merge?

Comment: What values are contained in a list and what does it mean to be inverted?

Comment: (1) Note that k-way merge will not do it, since there might be dupes among elements, which you need to removed. (2) How are you inverted indexes implemented? an array? a B+ tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-Way merge is optimal. It has `O(log(k)*n)` ops [where `n` is the number of elements in all lists combined].

It is easy to see it cannot be done better - as @jpalecek mentioned, otherwise you could sort any array better then `O(nlogn)` by splitting it into chunks [inverted indexes] of size 1.

- Note: This answer assumes it is important that inverted indexes
  [resulting array] will be sorted. This assumption is true for most
  applications that use inverted indexes, especially in the
  Information-Retrieval area. This feature [sorted indexes] allows
  elegant and quick intersection of indexes.
- Note: that standard k-way merge allows duplications, you will have to
  make sure that if an element is appearing in two lists, it will be
  added only once [easy to do it by simply checking the last element in
  the target array before adding].

Comment: Wouldn't k-way merge have at least `O(log(k)*n)` time complexity, rather than `O(n)`? Otherwise, you could sort any array in `O(n)` (taking each element as one list).

Comment: @jpalecek: You are absoloutly right, I have no idea what made me write this absourd statement [Guess I thaught of `k` as a constant, and it obviously not in here]. editted.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need the resulting array to be sorted, the best approach would be using a hash table to mark which of the elements you have seen. This way, you can get `O(n)` (`n` being the total number of elements) time complexity.

Something along the lines of (Perl):

```
my %seen;
@merged = grep { exists $seen{$_} ? 0 : ($seen{$_} = 1) } (map {(@$_)} @inputs);
```

Comment: inverted indexes are sorted by default - the result will not be an inverted index.